# Google sheets importhtml refresh error management

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, refresh

I have a spreadsheet that imports from various websites 10 tables using importhtml. I have a refresh script which helps me to update that data every 30 minutes. This is working fine. My problem is that plenty of times one or more of the importhtml fails which has as result all the cells that are using the data i am importing to give wrong results. Is there any way to keep the data I had taken earlier from importhtml if there is an error at refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

maybe not what you need, but try to wrap your imports into 1-2 IFERRORs like:

```
=IFERROR(IMPORTHTML(...); IMPORTHTML(...))
```

or:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IMPORTHTML(...); IMPORTHTML(...)); IMPORTHTML(...))
```

this way if some importing error occurs the IFERROR will re-try it. it may help in some cases - ofc not always.